# How to parse my JSON data to String in KENDO GRID?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

how can i format this object Object to its actual values ?
I want this json object to display its actual values in a specific kendo grid column .
Can someone please help me and teach me how to do it ?

This is the image of the kendo grid with the result ,

[image]

While here is the code that I am using in my view .
Can please someone help .

```
            contact : new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport:{
                read:{
                    type: "GET",
                    url:"reservation/list",
                    dataType:"json",
                    contentType: "application/json; chartset=utf-8"
                },
                update: {
                    url: "contacts/update",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: "contacts/destroy",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type:"POST"
                },
                create: {
                    url: "contacts/store",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type:"POST"
                }
            },
            schema:{
                model:{
                    id:"id",
                    fields:{
                        Purpose:
                        {
                            type:"string",
                            validation:{required:true}
                        },
                        RoomID:
                        {
                            from: "RoomID.room_name",
                            type: "string"
                        },
                        Equipments:
                        {  
                            from: "Equipments",
                            type: "string"
                        },
                        start:
                        {
                            type:"date",
                            validation:{required:true}
                        },
                        end:
                        {
                            type:"date",
                            validation:{required:true}
                        },
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize:10
        }),
        init : function(e){
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: this.contact,
                selectable: true,
                height:600,
                editable: "popup",
                filterable: true,
                sortable: {
                            mode: "multiple",
                            allowUnsort: true,
                            showIndexes: true
                        },
                toolbar: ["search"],
                columns: [
                    { 
                        field: "Purpose",
                        title:"Purpose" 
                    },
                    { 
                        field: "RoomID",
                        title:"Room", 
                    },
                    { 
                        field: "Equipments",
                        title:"Equipments", 
                    },
                    { 
                        field: "start",
                        title:"Start",
                        //template: '#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(start), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")#' 
                        format: "{0:MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm tt}",
                        parseFormats: ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.zz"]
                    },
                    { 
                        field: "end",
                        title:"End",
                        //template: '#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(end), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")#'
                        format: "{0:MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm tt}",
                        parseFormats: ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.zz"] 
                    },
                            { 
                                command: ["edit", "destroy"],
                                title: "&nbsp;", 
                                width: "250px" 
                            }
                        ],
                pageable:{
                    pageSize:10,
                    refresh:true,
                    buttonCount:5,
                    messages:{
                        display:"{0}-{1}of{2}"
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        });
       kendo.bind($("#whole"),model);
       model.init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help you out with templating out the results.

https://dojo.telerik.com/ICOceLUj

In the example above I have created a custom column that takes the incoming row object and then parsed the name of the item and the category object into a single template.

To achieve this I have added the template property and used a function with an external template script to handle the manipulation. I personally find this easier to manage than trying to inline a complex client template (especially if you have logic involved)

So this is how we set it up initially:

```
{ title: "custom template", template:"#=customTemplate(data)#"  }
```

obviously you will change it to the property you need to look at in your model.

then the function is a couple of lines of code:

```
 function customTemplate(data){
                var template = kendo.template($('#customTemplate').html()); 
                var result = template(data); 
                return result;
              }
```

so this takes the `customTemplate` template i have created for this and renders it as html and then it will apply the data where appropriate. The template looks like this:

```
 <script id="customTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">

          <div>
          <h5> #:data.ProductName#</h5>

          <h4>#: JSON.stringify(data.Category, null, 4) #</h4>

          </div>


          </script>
```

You can then customize this template to how you need it to look for your specific needs. You can then either create a source template for the items and then map the values back as single string or have the logic for this in the template. Which ever is most sensible in your case.

For more info on templating please look at this link:

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview

Answer (score 0):

You can use kendo.stringify in your column template.
Example:

```js
kendo.stringify(YourProperty)
```